# Bash Script through PHP

Tags: php, bash

I'm having problems trying to run the following script through php using the shell_exec() function.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/sshpass -p 'password' /usr/bin/rsync -avzhe -O 
"ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p port"
--exclude '*html' --include='R*' --exclude '*' 
username@ipaddress:/location/ /location
```

When I run this script in Terminal or through php shell_exec() I receive the following error:

```
Unexpected remote arg: username@IP:/location/
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1201) [sender=3.0.6]
```

If I remove the '-O' from the rsync part it works fine in terminal but through php I get the following error:

```
rsync: failed to set times on "/destination_location/.": Operation not permitted (1)
rsync: mkstemp "/location/.file.pSnb11" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync: mkstemp "/location/.file.hR7VUM" failed: Permission denied (13)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at     main.c(1505) [generator=
```

Below is the php code.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
     shell_exec('/location/rsync.sh');
}
?>
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<p>
    <button name="button">Run Script</button>
</p>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: A hint: what user runs your script?

Comment: since you get the error when running via terminial, its nothing to do with phhp

Comment: Root user runs it in terminal. @Dragon If you read the full post you will note that I said if you remove "-O" from rsync it runs fine in terminal but has more errors running through php.

Answer (score 1):

As others have suggested you are likely facing a permissions problem because when you run the code through the webserver, the webserver is running as a different user than `root`.

You can simulate the php call by first determining which user your webserver runs as. On Ubuntu for example this is `www-data`.

Then you can use `sudo` from the command line to test the call, `sudo -u www-data my-bash-script`. You should be able to sort out the permission problems this way and then you can try again via php and your webserver.

Comment: Exactly. To determine user that php uses to call script just try `shell_exec('whoami');`

Comment: @Scony Where can I find the output of shell_exec('whoami'); Trying to search the logs for it.

Comment: Try hitting it from from your browser `var_dump(shell_exec('whoami'));`

Comment: @quickshiftin when I run the script with sudo -u daemon I get the same error as through php. Now the issue is how do I allow the script to run as root. I know people will say don't give root access but this is running on a private network.

Comment: I don't think you want to run it as `root`. Rather you want to open up permissions in other places with a special group or even allowances for `daemon` specifically (though group permissions would be cleaner IMO). One other option I would suggest in lieu of that would be creating a `sudo` entry for your specific command (saved as a BASH script) for the `daemon` user. Then `daemon` could run *that command* via `sudo`.

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem by using shell_exec('sudo script.sh').

This required me to change the sudoers config.

I had to comment out
Defaults requiretty

And add that the user requires NOPASSWD to run the scripts.

Thanks for the help everyone.